# How to split a DataFrame into chunks, run apply(), and then re-stack into 1 DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding

This is part 2 of a problem I am trying to solve to geocode a DataFrame of addresses while staying within the thresholds to the API providers.  Yesterday I got help with the requests per second limitation ([Is there a slower or more controlled alternative to .apply()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737760/is-there-a-slower-or-more-controlled-alternative-to-apply)), but now I need to solve for the daily limit. My DataFrame has roughly 25K rows, and the daily limit is 2,500, so I need to split it approximately 10 times.  Since I consume a certain amount of daily requests with debugging and development, I think it's safe to split into chunks of 2K. Here is what I have so far:

```
def f(x, delay=5): 
    # Function for .apply() with speed limiter    
    sleep(delay)
    return geolocator.geocode(x)

for g, df in df_clean.groupby(np.arange(len(df_clean)) // 2000):
    df['coord'] = df['Address'].apply(f).apply(lambda x: (x.latitude, x.longitude))
    sleep(untilNextDay)
```

So what I don't know how to do, is stitch those chunked dataframes back together.  I could write them out to csv I guess, but I'm sure there has to be a better way.

Comment: Storing it in csvs might be better than storing it in memory overnight: that way if your computer crashes you don't lose a day's work. If not: you can use [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to put the dataframes back together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the dataframes to a list and concatenate them back later.

```
df_list = []

df_list.append(df['coord'])

pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something I've done to limit RAM utilization. Create a dictionary of dataframes .You can change the 500000 to 2500 maybe.

```
df_dict = {n: df.iloc[n:n+500000, :] 
           for n in range(0, len(df), 500000)}
```

Then of course just use whatever dict you'd like for processing. Or hit all the keys with a 24 hour sleep in between or something.