# googletrans JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, error-handling, translation

I'm trying to translate a column of Chinese addresses into English. I followed the documentation here: [new column with coordinates using geopy pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414481/new-column-with-coordinates-using-geopy-pandas). It worked the first time (about 30 minutes ago). All of a sudden, when I re-ran it, it threw me an error. Doesn't matter I restart the kernel, it does not work now. Does anyone know what is going on? How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Sample df (edit request from Zaraki Kenpachi)

```
Full Chinese Address 
湖北省荆州市洪湖市洪湖经济开发区万家墩大道1号
江西省九江市共青城工业新区
湖北孝感市孝南区毛陈镇孝武大道198号
```

Code

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

df['Translated English Address'] = df['Full Chinese Address'].apply(translator.translate, src='zh-CN', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))

# df= xin_loc.dropna(subset=['Translated English Address'])

df.head()
```

Error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: i get proper response from you code with basic Chinese example. Can you post few lines of china addresses where you got errors?

Comment: Hello Zaraki, Thanks for your reply. This code translated the address the first time I ran it but when I re-ran it, it gave me this error. I have tried restarted kernel a few times and it simply doesn't work like the first time anymore. Anyhow, here is the edited sample Chinese addresses.

Comment: I have tested posted addresses and all of them seems to be working well: `No. 1, Wanjiadun Avenue, Honghu Economic Devel...`,  `Gongqingcheng Industrial Zone, Jiujiang City, ..`, `198 Xiaowu Avenue, Maochen Town, Xiaonan Distr...`

Comment: Thanks again, Zaraki. Yes, the code worked well the first time I ran it too. But after about 30 minutes, I re-ran it and it gave me the error. That is why I'm posting the question.

Comment: try to set `encoding` while reading from csv data file. `encoding="GBK"`

Comment: Thanks, Zaraki. I'm currently doing a pd.read_excel(). How do I reset the encoding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221614/discussion-between-zaraki-kenpachi-and-matthias-gallagher).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this problem by turning on a VPN. Apparently this Google translate API has an unannounced daily limit. It blocks your IP address once you exceed the daily limit.