# How to Find the Distance Between Two Columns of Longitude and Latitude in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, geospatial, travel-time

I have a dataframe with two different locations on it. I have been able to find their longitude and latitudes using `geolocator` and using this [old Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414481/new-column-with-coordinates-using-geopy-pandas). Now I've gotten stuck trying to find the distance between these two columns of locations. I've been following [this website's](https://www.quantbarbie.com/blog/2018/7/11/calculate-the-distance-between-two-places-in-python) information trying to us `geodesic` as it directs.

The goal is to create a fifth and final column the shows me the distances between my locations. I'm getting an error that says:

> ValueError: When creating a Point from sequence, it must not have more than 3 items.

I have created a fake dataset of only a few but please be aware my real dataset is very big so I need to replicate this over thousands of rows that will have NaNs in it. The treatment is the same. The logic may not make sense with how I had to create this fake dataset but it throws up the same error as my original dataset. The logic gets me where I need to go with my original data that possesses many more unique values for both columns of location values.

```
 places_data = pd.DataFrame(
{"Place_1": ["Disneyland Park", "Empire State Building", "Yosemite Park", "Disney World Park", "Rockefeller Tower", "Grand Canyon"],   
 "Places": ["Peaches", "Apples", "Peaches", "Peaches", "Apples", "Peaches"]}
      )

 other_places = places_data.copy()

 other_places.loc[(other_places["Places"] == "Peaches"), "Sites"] = "Georgia Aquarium"
 other_places.loc[(other_places["Places"] == "Apples"), "Sites"] = "World of Coca-Cola"

 other_places["Loc_1"] = other_places["Place_1"].apply(geolocator.geocode).apply(lambda x: (x.latitude, x.longitude))
 other_places["Loc_2"] = other_places["Sites"].apply(geolocator.geocode).apply(lambda x: (x.latitude, x.longitude))

 places_data['Loc_1'] = places_data.Place_1.map(dict(other_places[['Place_1','Loc_1']].to_numpy()))
 places_data['Loc_2'] = places_data.Places.map(dict(other_places[['Places','Loc_2']].to_numpy()))


 places_data["Distance"] = geodesic(places_data["Loc_1"], places_data["Loc_2"]).miles
```